# Critical section via constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11, embedded, critical-section

In embedded programming there is a need to create atomic sections of code - so called critical sections. They are usually implemented via macros, for example, like this:

```
#define ENTER_CRITICAL() int saved_status_ = CPU_STATUS_REGISTER; __disable_irq();
#define EXIT_CRITICAL()  CPU_STATUS_REGISTER = saved_status_
```

I.e. on entering the status of interrupts (enabled or disabled) is saved; on exit - it is restored. The problem is that additional variable is needed for this.

My question is: is it possible to make critical sections via constexpr functions (and to get rid of macros what so ever)?

Comment: you could just get rid of the macro by implementing it as a function, or has that any unwanted side effects?

Comment: Then it has to be one function for enter and exit, since they use common variable (which has to be static, of course). Hmm, maybe that's the answer. I need to think about it.

Comment: or you could get rid of the static variable and use a local one?

Comment: Ehm, but the value of local variable will be lost as soon as the function "EnterCritical()" will hit return point.

Comment: If there is state, then you can't `constexpr`.

Comment: Are you sure you have to save the registers ? Disabling the interrupts is sufficient in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RAII solution would be traditional:

```
struct CriticalSection {
  int saved_status_;
  void Enter() {
    saved_status_ = CPU_STATUS_REGISTER;
    __disable_irq();
  }
  CriticalSection() { Enter(); }
  void Exit() {
    CPU_STATUS_REGISTER = saved_status_;
  }
  ~CriticalSection() {
    Exit(); // Can you call this more than once safely?  Dunno.
  }
};
```

you'd use it like this:

```
void foo() {
  // unprotected code goes here
  {
    CriticalSection _;
    // protected code goes here
  }
  // unprotected code goes here
}
```

Doing this without any state is not possible, because `CPU_STATUS_REGISTER` is a run time value.  State in C/C++ is mostly stored in variables.

I strongly suspect that, under any non-trivial optimization level, the above RAII class will compile to the exact same code that your macros compiled to, except you no longer have to remember to EXIT_CRITICAL().

Comment: Oh wow, that's brilliant! Thank you, i've never heard about this.

Comment: @Amomum [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is one of the more useful programming features of C++.  Enjoy!